# How can I solve for the points of an arbitrary trapezoid inscribed inside of a triangle?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Given the following coordinate points:

[image: trapezoid]

Write an algorithm (in pseudocode) to solve for `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`.

This is what I have so far:

```
 var y1, y2, y3, y4 = 50, 50, 75, 75;

 var offset1 = tan(60) * y1;

 var offset2 = tan(60) * (y2 - y1);

 var x1 = 200 + offset1;

 var x3 = 200 + offset1 + offset2;
```

Comment: It'll be helpful to edit your post and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Try using similar triangles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the right triangle `{ (200,0) (350,300) (350,0) }` (see the illustration below).

Since the big and the small triangles sharing the `(Xb, Yb)` corner are similar, the ratio of the length of the red side `(X,Y)-(Xb,Y)` to the length of `(Xb,Y)-(Xb,Yb)` is the same as the ratio of `(Xa,Ya)-(Xb,Ya)` to `(Xb,Ya)-(Xb,Yb)`.

[image: Illustration]

Since `(X,Y)-(Xb,Y)` is your only unknown, you could figure out the answer by solving the equation

```
Xb-X   Xb-Xa
---- = -----
Yb-Y   Yb-Ya
```

Therefore,

```
         (Xb-Xa)*(Yb-Y)
X = Xb - --------------
              Yb-Ya
```

Comment: The visual aid helped a great deal.  How did you draw that diagram?

Answer (score 1):

You know the equations of all the three lines (sides) of the triangle. (You can derive it by the vertex points)

Just plug in the values of y and get the x coordinates.

EDIT: If you know two points on a line (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), then the equation of the line is:

```
y2-y1   y - y1
----- = ------
x2-x1   x - x1
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'm trying to figure out; how to derive the x coordinates by the vertex points of the triangle.